# Whats the difference between instanceMethods and getterMethods in sequelizejs?

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

```
sequelize.define("aModel", {
    text: DataTypes.TEXT
}, {
    instanceMethods: {
        getme1: function() {
            return this.text.toUpperCase();
        }
    },
    getterMethods: {
        getme2: function() {
            return this.text.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
});
```

[InstanceMethods](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#expansion-of-models) and [getterMethods](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#getters-setters) seem to accomplish the same thing, allowing to access virtual keys. Why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instance methods you call with `Model.method()`, but if you have a getter method called `text` it will be called when you do `instance.text`. Similarly the setter methods get used when you do `instance.text = 'something'`.

Example:

```
var Model = sequelize.define("aModel", {
    text: DataTypes.TEXT
}, {
    instanceMethods: {
        getUpperText: function() {
            return this.text.toUpperCase();
        }
    },
    getterMethods: {
        text: function() {
            // use getDataValue to not enter an infinite loop
            // http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/#getdatavaluekey-any
            return this.getDataValue('text').toUpperCase();
        }
    },
    setterMethods: {
        text: function(text) {
            // use setDataValue to not enter an infinite loop
            // http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/#setdatavaluekey-value
            this.setDataValue('text', text.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
});

Model.create({
    text: 'foo'
}).then(function(instance) {
    console.log(instance.getDataValue('text')); // foo
    console.log(instance.getUpperText()); // FOO
    console.log(instance.text); // FOO

    instance.text = 'BAR';

    console.log(instance.getDataValue('text')) // bar
    console.log(instance.text); // BAR
});
```

Comment: Please update this answer with v4 breaking changes : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#breaking-changes